# Does a FTP-upload via Java by JavaScript exist?

Tags: java, silverlight, ftp

I have following scenario: A silverlight-plugin records some audio and stores this in a `byte[]` which I'd like to upload to FTP. Unfortunately FTP-upload in Silverlight is pain, as I'd need to implement sockets.
So I though, well ...

[image]

So, does there exist a Java-Applet which does that job **and** is open-source? Ah, and ... yes ... only real (S)FTP would be ideal, as I'll try to upload laaaaarge files ... oh, and yes ... any HTML5-specific funky-stuff is (unfortunately) not possible ... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please understand that Applet and JavaScript are client-side . You still have to use server-side scripts to perform FTP operations. Probably JSP / Servlet has to be used in your case.

Comment: oh ... take a look @ http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/integralftp/overview.html. they provide (a .jar-file, which can be included as an applet) exactly what I need, but it ain't opensource :(

Comment: and btw - I really know the difference between client- and server-side. that's the reason I am asking this question, because I do not know any other scenario where a client-side code could do a real FTP-upload.

Comment: I think what the JAR file doing is to create a FTP client, connecting to FTP server...

Comment: exactly what I want and need. *and* it does not involve any server-side scripting stuff.

Comment: See if this helps you : http://commons.apache.org/net/ and its example: http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html